# Run a script for multiple lists within the same script editor

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I know almost nothing about javascript, clearly. I have the script below that gets a list by name and it works perfectly. My problem is that when I copy it and insert a new list name for a second list, it does not work. I've tried many things but cannot figure out how to alter/combine the code to work for multiple lists. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Using SharePoint 2013 Foundation Server

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
GetProducts();
});

function GetProducts() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('HRKPI');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems("");
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
var listItemEnum = collListItem.getEnumerator();
var ProductInfo = '<div>';

while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
var oListItem = listItemEnum.get_current();
ProductInfo += '<div id="pParentSquareKPI"> <p id="pKPIName">' +
oListItem.get_item('Name') + '</p>' +
'<p id="pKPIValue">' + oListItem.get_item('Value') + '</p> </div>';
}

ProductInfo += '</div>';
$('#products').html(ProductInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error after you change the list name... If Yes, please add the error here.

Comment: How do I check for errors? The code works but then the original list disappears as if I can only have one at a time

Comment: You can check for errors in browsers console window. Also, try appending the second lists data to another html div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. The only thing I did differently that my prior attempts was I changed the variable 'clientContext' for the GetNews() function to ensure it was different from the GetProducts() function. Thanks all for your help!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
GetProducts();
GetNews();
});

function GetProducts() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('HRKPI');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems("");
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
}

function GetNews() {
var nclientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var nList = nclientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('NewsInfo');
this.ncollListItem = nList.getItems("");
nclientContext.load(ncollListItem);
nclientContext.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
var listItemEnum = collListItem.getEnumerator();
var nlistItemEnum = ncollListItem.getEnumerator();
var ProductInfo = '<div>';
var NewsInfoHTML = '<div>';

while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
var oListItem = listItemEnum.get_current();
ProductInfo += '<div id="pParentSquareKPI"> <p id="pKPIName">' +
oListItem.get_item('Name') + '</p>' +
'<p id="pKPIValue">' + oListItem.get_item('Value') + '</p> </div>';
}

while (nlistItemEnum.moveNext()) {
var nListItem = nlistItemEnum.get_current();
NewsInfoHTML += '<div id="nParentSquare"> <p id="nNewsName">' +
nListItem.get_item('Name') + '</p>' +
'<p id="nNewsID">' + nListItem.get_item('ID') + '</p> </div>';
}

ProductInfo += '</div>';
$('#products').html(ProductInfo);

NewsInfoHTML += '</div>';
$('#news').html(NewsInfoHTML);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

Change List name on below line

```
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('HRKPI');
```

As your code says that you are using `Name` and `Value` column in code so make sure you have that column on your list. Or you need to change that column internal name as per your new list columns

```
ProductInfo += '<div id="pParentSquareKPI"> <p id="pKPIName">' +
oListItem.get_item('Name') + '</p>' +
'<p id="pKPIValue">' + oListItem.get_item('Value') + '</p> </div>';
```

Comment: I've tried this. The code works but then my original list data disappears.

Comment: Then you should bind data on other div or append on current div